# How to set a 30 second request timeout in asp.net mvc website

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, timeout, connection-timeout

We are trying to make sure that requests to our website timeout after 30 seconds. I have tried setting the executionTimeout property to 30 as well as setting script execution timeout.

None of these seem to work although compilation debug is set to false.

For testing purposes, I am setting the timeouts to 5 seconds. I also have an endpoint that calls a thread sleep for a given amount of seconds (passed through a GET parameter).

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are you mean "session timeout"? Forms authentication in web.config has `timeout` attribute available to be set. Include additional info you want to do with (web.config contents etc.).

Comment: Are you using WebAPi Controller or MVC controller to process request?

Answer (score -1):

Can you try this in your webconfig:

```
<system.web>
    ...
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="180" />
    ...
</system.web>
```